# Viewing updates to HTML file in browser after editing in Notepad++

Tags: browser, notepad++

Editing an HTML file in Notepad++ I now want to see the updated page in Google Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Is there a shortcut that I can use to see the changes as rendered through the different browsers after editing my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh the page using F5 or Ctrl-F5.

Comment: shift-f5 might be one to try too. it's what i've always used.. when I used IE more. there's a bit of discussion http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47383 and  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad0040ed-b8e7-40da-9799-2e14f6cd9419/  but cltr-f5 (which you mention) might be universal or fairly universal.. since there's an absurdly titled website here http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/  that doesn't mention shift-f5  Though that's probably more the fault of the site than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the results in another window, you will have to right click on your html file and select open with ... (another browser).

Answer (score 0):

I found that by right-clicking on the title in the file tabs, and then clicking "full file path to clip board" I was able to paste the full file path into Chrome and then view it from there.

I didn't see an "open with..." option but this option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Browser Refresh](https://deskjs.wordpress.com/browser-refresh). It's a free and portable Windows application which does exactly that, plus even more. As of currently, it supports *Google Chrome*, Google Chrome Canary, *Mozilla Firefox*, Firefox Developer Edition, *Internet Explorer*, Opera Browser, Yandex Browser, Blisk Browser, and Vivaldi Browser. Have fun with it.

Comment: What does this do that the browsers' built-in refresh capability (F5) doesn't do?  … … … … … … … … … P.S. Are you associated with this program?  Did you have anything to do with developing it?